# how to add profile and user in mikrotk by tik4net?

Tags: c#, mikrotik

I already tried this

```
     var cmd = connection.CreateCommandAndParameters("/tool/user-manager/user/add", "customer", "kamrul",
                "username", "test007", "password", "12345678");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but giving this error:

```
    no such command or directory (user-manager)
```

Answer (score -1):

hi I don't know about the tiknet but in mikrotik terminal you can add user using this command

```
 /user add name=username password=strongpassword group=master disabled=no
```

I guess you can use it in your code like

```
var cmd = connection.CreateCommandAndParameters("/user/add", "name", "username","password", "strongpassword", "group", "master","disabled","no");
```

hope this helps